# Group values corresponding to different duplicated keywords in a query in Gsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to test some basic sums with large data sets with duplicated words in a row in this Gsheets [Test duplicates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZQDcfzej2gsle7YGEhIYP_LFluDaGM_dEXcklxXBbY/edit?usp=sharing)

I like to get the top 4 suppliers by country, based on volume but I have the condition that suppliers are duplicated in different positions in different rows. A first approach was to remove duplicates by grouping within a query and just sum the Kgs, but that's missing some of the values as seen on the query cell result.

```
=query($A$3:$C$6;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE A matches '.*Walmart.*' and B='USA' ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC LABEL SUM(C) 'Kgs'";0)
```

Any more efficient approaches?

Comment: So, what will be your desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be something like this:

Comment: 1. SUM of the values (kg) by Country and supplier (in common). i.e. Walmart USA 150084

Answer (score 0):

try with `group by`:

```
=QUERY(A3:C6; 
 "select B,sum(C) 
  where A matches '.*Walmart.*' 
    and B='USA' 
  group by B 
  order by sum(C) desc 
  label sum(C) 'Kgs'"; 0)
```